# Solve the integral equation (C.S.I.R)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, integral-equations

Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ be the eigenvalues and $f_1 , f_2$ be the corresponding eigenfunctions for the homogeneous integral equation:

$$ \phi(x) - \lambda \int_0^1 (xt +2x^2) \phi(t) dt = 0 $$

Then:

1. $\lambda_1 = -18 - 6 \sqrt{10} , \lambda_2 = -18 + 6 \sqrt{10}$
2. $\lambda_1 = -36 - 12 \sqrt{10} , \lambda_2 = -36 + 12 \sqrt{10}$
3. $\int_0^1f_1(x)f_2(x) dx = 1$
4. $\int_0^1f_1(x)f_2(x) dx = 0$

I solved simply and got that the values of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ belong to (1).

Please tell me about options (3) and (4).

Thank you.

Comment: What does the "CSIR" in the title mean?

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila : It is an organisation in INDIA which conducted an exam .

Comment: How do you get $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$? This topic seems new to me. Thanks!

Comment: @ mike : see this http://books.google.co.in/books?id=4s4RUWOM3XgC&pg=PA7&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 2):

Let's rewrite your equation in the following form:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\lambda}\phi(x) = x\int_{0}^{1}t\phi(t) \mathrm{d}t + 2x^{2}\int_{0}^{1} \phi(t) \mathrm{d}t = c_{1}x + c_{2}x^{2}
\end{align}
for $c_{1}: = \int_{0}^{1}t\phi(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$ and $c_{2}:= 2\int_{0}\phi(t)\, \mathrm{d}t$. From this we can see that $\phi$ is a quadratic polynomial with no constant term.

Substituting $\phi(x) = c_{1}x + c_{2}x^{2}$, we find that 
\begin{align}
\frac{c_{1}}{\lambda} x + \frac{c_{2}}{\lambda}x^{2} 
&=x \int_{0}^{1} t(c_{1}t+ c_{2}t^{2}) \, \mathrm{d}t + 2x^{2} \int_{0}^{1} c_{1}t + c_{2}t^{2} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&=x(c_{1}/3 + c_{2}/4) + 2x^{2}(c_{1}/2 + c_{2}/3)
\end{align}
so that 
\begin{align}
\frac{c_{1}}{\lambda} &= \frac{c_{1}}{3} + \frac{c_{2}}{4} \\
\frac{c_{2}}{\lambda} &= c_{1} + \frac{2c_{2}}{3} \\
\end{align}
It can be verified that if both $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are nonzero, then $\lambda = -18 \pm 6\sqrt{10}$. 
Since $c_{1} = \left(\frac{1}{\lambda} - \frac{2}{3}  \right)c_{2}$
\begin{align}
f_{1}(x) &= -\left(\frac{1}{18+6\sqrt{10}} + \frac{2}{3}\right)c_{2}x + c_{2}x^{2}
= -\frac{1}{6}(1+\sqrt{10})c_{2}x + c_{2}x^{2} \\
f_{2}(x) &= -\left(\frac{1}{18-6\sqrt{10}} + \frac{2}{3}\right)c_{2}'x + c_{2}'x^{2} = -\frac{1}{6}(1-\sqrt{10})c_{2}'x + c_{2}'x^{2}
\end{align}
so that 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} f_{1}(x)f_{2}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
&=
c_{2}c_{2}' \int_{0}^{1} x^{4} -\frac{1}{3}x^{3} - \frac{1}{4}x^{4} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{c_{2}c_{2}'}{30}
\end{align}
So we can't claim that these eigenfunctions are orthogonal, or that their inner product is 1, unless we choose a scaling such that $c_{2}c_{2}' = 30$.

Comment: @ Nick Thompson : Thanks

Comment: I have a confusion that If we choose  $c_2c_2'=0$ then we get $\int_0^1{f_1(x)f_2(x)dx}=0$ and if we choose  $c_2c_2'=30$ then we get $\int_0^1{f_1(x)f_2(x)dx}=1$. then which is the right answer? please help me to understand this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This work is almost completed.

Define $g(t)=\int_0^t \phi(s) ds$ and $h(t)=\int_0^t s \phi(s) ds$
Because $\phi(0)=0$, we have $g(0)=0$ and $h(0)=0$.

Using integration by parts, we have

$$h(t)=\int_0^t t \phi(t) dt=t\left(\int_0^t\phi(s) ds\right)-\int_0^t\left(\int_0^s \phi(r) dr\right)ds$$
$$\implies h(t)=tg(t)-\int_0^t g(s) ds......(1)$$

The original equation becomes:
$$\phi(x) = \lambda x\ h(1) +2 \lambda x^2 g(1)......(2)$$

And
$$g(t)=\int_0^t \phi(s) ds=\frac{1}{2}\lambda h(1)t^2 +\frac{2}{3} \lambda g(1) t^3......(3)$$

$$h(t)=\int_0^t s\phi(s) ds=\frac{1}{3}\lambda h(1)t^3 +\frac{2}{4} \lambda g(1) t^4......(4)$$

Therefore

$$g(1)=\frac{1}{2} \lambda h(1)+\frac{2}{3} \lambda g(1)...(5)$$

$$h(1)=\frac{1}{3}\lambda h(1) +\frac{2}{4} \lambda g(1)......(6)$$

Setting $\mu=\lambda^{-1}$ in (5) and (6), we have:
$$
        \left(\begin{matrix} \frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3}  \\ \frac{2}{4} & \frac{1}{3}  \\ \end{matrix}\right)
        \left(\begin{matrix} g(1)  \\ h(1)   \\ \end{matrix}\right)=
        \mu \left(\begin{matrix} g(1)  \\ h(1)   \\ \end{matrix}\right)......(7)
$$

Once you found two eigen values you can substitute them into (7) and solve for $g(1)$ as a function of $h(1)$.  You may then fix $h(1)$ by some kind of normalization.

Finally you can substitute $\lambda_{1,2}$ and $g(1),h(1)$ into (2) to obtain the eigen functions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$.

I hope that you can pick it up from here.

-mike

Comment: @ mike : how to find the right answer.

Comment: I think it is almost there!